# Possible to connect to Wallet from android (java/kotlin)?

Tags: dapps, ethereum-wallet-dapp, dapp-development, android, walletconnect

I would like to program a mobile DApp which connects to a wallet, like a webapp. I thought it may be possible with WalletConnect. Has anyone ever done this?

Thanks!

Comment: This is where i have to promote my library, it has sample app and code: https://github.com/jemshit/WalletConnect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed possible with WalletConnect.

There is a Kotlin library available (both for v1 and v2 of WalletConnect).

For v1 you can use: https://github.com/WalletConnect/kotlin-walletconnect-lib

You need to generate a WallectConnect session with a valid bridge server (e.g. for testing `https://bridge.walletconnect.org/`): https://github.com/WalletConnect/kotlin-walletconnect-lib/blob/1486aa2d374d2e64614bf6d467a4076f1215d1a0/sample/app/src/main/java/io/walletconnect/example/ExampleApplication.kt#L52

Then you use this to create an intent and open any installed wallet that can handle the `wc` protocol: https://github.com/WalletConnect/kotlin-walletconnect-lib/blob/1486aa2d374d2e64614bf6d467a4076f1215d1a0/sample/app/src/main/java/io/walletconnect/example/MainActivity.kt#L65

For the new v2 version for Kotlin you can find the documentation here: https://docs.walletconnect.com/2.0/quick-start/wallets/kotlin

Here is the source: https://github.com/WalletConnect/WalletConnectKotlinV2